Finding the velocity and current on a 'moving' resistor
I came across this example which to me looks kind of non-sensical. I think the Hall effect is supposed to be used to help solve this, but I struggle to use it as I think that there is some information missing.
The text goes as follows:

On stationary conductive rails of negligible resistance, and mutual distance l is connected an ideal voltage source of electromagnetic force E. On the rails lies and resistor of resistance R, that can slide on the rails and remain in contact with them. The Friction force between them can be viewed as a constant Ff. The whole system is situated upon an magnetic field of induction B normal to the plain of the rails.
a) Calculate the velocity of the resistor; b) Calculate the current; in this state. Number values E=10V, R=3 Ohms, B=0.8T, l=1m, Ff=2N

Provided illustration:

I really tried everything I know to make sense of this but everything I come up with needs more information.


I really tried everything I know to make sense of this but but
everything I come up with need more information.

Your diagram shows a simple motor (or actuator) where the resistor will be attracted to (or repelled from) the source E because of the resident magnetic field B and the magnetic field produced by current circulating in the resistor. So, you need to decide firstly whether the current flow acts against the resident magnetic field or, whether it adds to it. This determines the direction of the resistor. Then you should use basic force equations to calculate the speed of the resistor: -

Image from Magnetic Force on a Current-Carrying Conductor. Note that this document also gives you the force formula (\$F=B\cdot I\cdot \ell\$)

Thank you for your feedback I will try it out

@VukoMijušković If we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.
